# Make function return different types haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads

I am completely new to haskell. I need a function that either returns an operator or returns an error message in the form of a string. For context I am building a Monadic Parser which accept doubles.

```
term'::Parser Double
term' = factor' `chainl1` mulop

addop, mulop :: Parser (Double -> Double -> Double)
mulop = do symbol "^" 
           return (**)
        +++ do symbol "*" 
               return (*)
        +++ do symbol "/"
               return (/)

addop = do symbol "+" 
           return (+)
        +++ do symbol "-"
               return (-)
```

The code above works well for returning the operator, however when I try expand on this by adding the error message I get compilation errors. Below is what I am attempting.

```
mulop :: Either (Parser (Double -> Double -> Double)) (Parser String)
mulop = do symbol "^" 
            return Left (**)
        +++ do symbol "*" 
               return Left (*)
        +++ do symbol "/" 
               return Left (/)
        +++ pure Right "ERROR MSG"
```

Comment: `return Left (**)` should be `return (Left (**))` (or `return $ Left (**)`). Otherwise you call `return` with two separate arguments, `Left` and `(**)` which makes no sense.

Comment: Why just not call `fail "ERROR MSG"`?

Comment: The idea is to handle it in the above manner and not raise an exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's only a single parser. It needs input to decide whether the output is an operator or an error-string. So the signature has to be

```
mulop :: Parser (Either (Double -> Double -> Double) String)
```

Actually there's something of a convention that when using `Either` as an exception-adding type, the error messages should be on the `Left`, so perhaps better make it

```
mulop :: Parser (Either String (Double -> Double -> Double))
```

In the implementation: be careful to get the syntax rules right. `return` and `pure` are just ordinary functions, not special keywords like `return` in procedural languages. So it needs to be `return $ Left (**)`.

Also make sure you get the indentation right. I would align this thus:

```
mulop = do symbol "^" 
           return $ Right (**)
    +++ do symbol "*" 
           return $ Right (*)
    +++ do symbol "/" 
           return $ Right (/)
    +++ pure (Left "ERROR MSG")
```

Alternatively, *don't* use `do` notation. You don't really need anything monadic here, you can instead use the [`<$` operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36-):

```
mulop = (Right (**) <$ symbol "^")
    +++ (Right (*) <$ symbol "*")
    +++ (Right (/) <$ symbol "/")
    +++ pure (Left "ERROR MSG")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it works perfectly!